# Could not find method compile() for arguments, org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting the following error

> Error:(17, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [file collection] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Please add some descriptive info or logcat .. @Agha

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this error after importing a previous project done on an earlier version of Android Studio. 
I. Upgrade your build tools version to 3.0.1 or later so that it recognizes the terms `testImplementation , androidTestImplementation, implementation`
II. Edit your build.gradle app file so that all `implementation` are replaced with `compile` 
Previous

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
// RecyclerView
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
```

Should now read

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

// RecyclerView
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
```

The above solution then generates an error about Aapt that is then fixed by adding the line below in the gradle.properties file

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Wonder if this was a fluke or it works every time